# What is the format of this time?

Tags: protocol, binary-diagnosis, gps

I'm trying to interpret a bunch of bytes I'm receiving from a GPS tracker.
There are 3 sequential bytes that I believe mean hours, minutes and seconds. I recorded timestamps along with the messages I receive and noticed this:

```
when hour 0: byte 1 in message is 0x30
when hour 1: byte 1 in message is 0x31
...

when minute 0: byte 2 in message is 0x30
when minute 1: byte 2 in message is 0x31
...
```

But some bytes are skipped as follows:

for hours:

```
Hou 10   16          2
----------------------
00: 48 - 30 - 00110000
01: 49 - 31 - 00110001
02: 50 - 32 - 00110010
03: 51 - 33 - 00110011
04: 52 - 34 - 00110100
05: 53 - 35 - 00110101
06: 54 - 36 - 00110110
07: 55 - 37 - 00110111
08: 56 - 38 - 00111000
09: 57 - 39 - 00111001 <- jump
10: 65 - 41 - 01000001
11: 66 - 42 - 01000010
12: 67 - 43 - 01000011
13: 68 - 44 - 01000100
14: 69 - 45 - 01000101
15: 70 - 46 - 01000110
16: 71 - 47 - 01000111
17: 72 - 48 - 01001000
18: 73 - 49 - 01001001
19: 74 - 4a - 01001010
20: 75 - 4b - 01001011
21: 76 - 4c - 01001100
22: 77 - 4d - 01001101
23: 78 - 4e - 01001110
```

for minutes and seconds:

```
min  10   16          2
-----------------------
00:  48 - 30 - 00110000
01:  49 - 31 - 00110001
02:  50 - 32 - 00110010
03:  51 - 33 - 00110011
04:  52 - 34 - 00110100
05:  53 - 35 - 00110101
06:  54 - 36 - 00110110
07:  55 - 37 - 00110111
08:  56 - 38 - 00111000
09:  57 - 39 - 00111001 <- jump
10:  65 - 41 - 01000001
11:  66 - 42 - 01000010
12:  67 - 43 - 01000011
13:  68 - 44 - 01000100
14:  69 - 45 - 01000101
15:  70 - 46 - 01000110
16:  71 - 47 - 01000111
17:  72 - 48 - 01001000
18:  73 - 49 - 01001001
19:  74 - 4a - 01001010
20:  75 - 4b - 01001011
21:  76 - 4c - 01001100
22:  77 - 4d - 01001101
23:  78 - 4e - 01001110
24:  79 - 4f - 01001111
25:  80 - 50 - 01010000
26:  81 - 51 - 01010001
27:  82 - 52 - 01010010
28:  83 - 53 - 01010011
29:  84 - 54 - 01010100
30:  85 - 55 - 01010101
31:  86 - 56 - 01010110
32:  87 - 57 - 01010111
33:  88 - 58 - 01011000
34:  89 - 59 - 01011001
35:  90 - 5a - 01011010 <- jump
36:  97 - 61 - 01100001
37:  98 - 62 - 01100010
38:  99 - 63 - 01100011
39: 100 - 64 - 01100100
40: 101 - 65 - 01100101
41: 102 - 66 - 01100110
42: 103 - 67 - 01100111
43: 104 - 68 - 01101000
44: 105 - 69 - 01101001
45: 106 - 6a - 01101010
46: 107 - 6b - 01101011
47: 108 - 6c - 01101100
48: 109 - 6d - 01101101
49: 110 - 6e - 01101110
50: 111 - 6f - 01101111
51: 112 - 70 - 01110000
52: 113 - 71 - 01110001
53: 114 - 72 - 01110010
54: 115 - 73 - 01110011
55: 116 - 74 - 01110100
56: 117 - 75 - 01110101
57: 118 - 76 - 01110110
58: 119 - 77 - 01110111
59: 120 - 78 - 01111000
```

Do you guys know of any encoding like this? Does it make sense? There would be any reason for encoding this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the numbers to ASCII, we get:

- 0 ~ 9 = `0` ~ `9` (0x30 ~ 0x39)
- 10 ~ 35 = `A` ~ `Z` (0x41 ~ 0x5a)
- 36 ~ 61 = `a` ~ `z` (0x61 ~ 0x7a)

It is encoded this way probably to make it human-readable.

Comment: Crazy way to encode!